# How to a space between each file when concatenating multiple files in Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, concatenation

I was trying to concatenate multiple files, but the last word of the each file combines with the next file's first word. How can i solve this issue?

```
import glob
read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")
with open(r"C:\Users\chii\Downloads\result.txt ", "wb") as outfile:
for f in read_files:
    with open(f,"rb",) as infile:
        outfile.write(infile.read())
```

`

Comment: What have you tried to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: oh i'm trying to concatenate them so that i could perform a tokenization.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new line after each insert, something like this.

```
with open(<YOUR_FILE>, "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
            outfile.write(os.linesep.encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the last line/word of the previous file is being blended with the first add this:

```py
import glob
read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")
with open(r"C:\Users\chii\Downloads\result.txt ", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f,"rb",) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
    outfile.write("\n")
```